# $Count depending on the first step of $facet

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to aggregate some data first and extract their result, and then calculate their total count, I've tried $facet to get the 2 results but I wasnt able to get the result I expect.

here is my first step, I need the output of this data besides the total count before skip and limit.

```
{
      $match: { $and: [{ batch: batchID }, { "$expr": { "$ne": ["$status", "deleted"] } }] }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'users',
        let: { "id": "$worker" },
        pipeline: [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$id"] } } },
          {
            "$project": {
              "firstName": 1,
              "lastName": 1,
              "candidateNo": 1,
              "emailAddress": 1,
              "worker.payrollProduct.agencyRef": 1
            }
          },
        ],
        as: 'worker'
      }
    },
    {
      $match: candidatesQuery
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$worker"
    },
    {
      $skip: Number(params.offset)
    }, 
    {
      $limit: Number(params.limit)
    }
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can also give us your sample dataset and expected output